Make clang-tidy warn about uninitialized array elements?
No matter what I try, I cannot get this code to produce any clang-tidy warnings:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void foo() {
  std::array<int, 500> i;
  int k[500];
  std::cout << "hello world " << i[0] << k[0] << std::endl;
}

void bar() {
  std::array<int, 1000> i;
  i.fill(0xcdcdcdcd);
}

int main() {
  bar();
  foo();
  return 0;
}

It produces this output:
hello world -842150451-842150451

I would like for clang-tidy to emit warnings that i[0] and k[0] are uninitialized. Is it (currently) capable of doing this?

Side-note: GCC is able to warn about k[0] at least.

GCC warns about both with optimizations enabled (at least -O1)
